# Configuring FireDac for cross platform development using Firebird 2.5

Tags: macos, delphi, firebird, firedac

I am creating a cross platform data aware app for windows and os x using Delphi 10.1 Berlin and firebird.  My Mac is running El Capitan.  My PC is running in Parallels virtual machine on the Mac.

The app on each platform is to connect to a firebird 2.5 server located on a Win 2008 server.  The win32 version compiles and connects without a problem.  The one for OS X, however, does not.

I have already downloaded and installed FB 2.5 on my Mac and set up PAserver properly.  For example, I have been able to connect to firebird on the Windows server from my Mac using RazorSQL.  I have also been able to compile a very simple "Hello world" project with just a button and a ShowMessage dialog and run it on the Mac.  So, I am sure PAserver is running correctly.

I created a barebones data aware application for testing.  Here is the form in text format:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object StringGrid1: TStringGrid
    Align = Client
    CanFocus = True
    ClipChildren = True
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 440.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    RowCount = 0
    Viewport.Width = 636.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 415.000000000000000000
  end
  object ToolBar1: TToolBar
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 7
    object NavigatorBindSourceDB1: TBindNavigator
      Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 7.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 241.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 25.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 0
      DataSource = BindSourceDB1
      xRadius = 4.000000000000000000
      yRadius = 4.000000000000000000
    end
  end
  object FDConnection1: TFDConnection
    Params.Strings = (
      'Database=E:\Shared Folders\Employees\Firebird\Databases\Test.fdb'
      'User_Name=SYSDBA'
      'Password= (intentionally deleted)'
      'Protocol=TCPIP'
      'Server=afmsasrv'
      'Port=3024'
      'ExtendedMetadata=True'
      'CharacterSet=win1252'
      'DriverID=FB25')
    Connected = True
    LoginPrompt = False
    Left = 440
    Top = 112
  end
  object FDGUIxWaitCursor1: TFDGUIxWaitCursor
    Provider = 'FMX'
    Left = 344
    Top = 120
  end
  object FDTable1: TFDTable
    Active = True
    IndexFieldNames = 'ID'
    Connection = FDConnection1
    UpdateOptions.UpdateTableName = 'PERSON'
    TableName = 'PERSON'
    Left = 272
    Top = 128
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = FDTable1
    Left = 216
    Top = 128
  end
  object BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = FDTable1
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 304
    Top = 224
  end
  object BindingsList1: TBindingsList
    Methods = <>
    OutputConverters = <>
    Left = 20
    Top = 5
    object LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB1: TLinkGridToDataSource
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = BindSourceDB1
      GridControl = StringGrid1
      Columns = <>
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the project I get the error below:

```
[FireDAC][Phys]-300. Driver [FB25] is not registered. Correct driver ID or define [FB25] virtual driver in FDDrivers.ini'. Process Project1 (1114)
```

I have added FDDrivers.ini to my project, as indicated in Embarcadero's FireDac documentation.  Here are the contents.

```
[FDDrivers.ini]
Encoding=UTF8

[FB25]
; FB25 virtual driver will use specified Firebird client library
BaseDriverID=FB
VendorLibWin32=C:\firebird\fb25_W32\bin\fbclient.dll
VendorLibWin64=C:\firebird\fb25_64\bin\fbclient.dll
VendorLibOSX32=/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Libraries/Versions/A/libfbclient.dylib
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Does `/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Libraries/Versions/A/libfbclient.dylib` exist?

Comment: Yes. That library exists on the Mac.